# Can you pass arguments to a pipe method of a DataFrame when using lambda?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a series of transformations on a dataframe, i wonder if i can use a function inline with the pipe method without having to use a defined function to apply it.

What i want:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45],
  "lon": [6.23, 6.24, 6.25],
  "lat": [-75.1, -75.2, -75.3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_transformed = (
  # Whole bunch of transformations including merge and spatial joins
  # which transform the original lon and lat columns
  .pipe(lambda x: gpd.GeoDataFrame,
          geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x['lon'], x['lat']),
          crs='EPSG:4326')
)
# This throws an error x is not defined
```

How i solved it:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

def turn_to_geo(df: pd.DataFrame, lat: str, lon: str) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    return gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,
                            geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df[lon], df[lat]),
                            crs='EPSG:4326')

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45],
  "lon": [6.23, 6.24, 6.25],
  "lat": [-75.1, -75.2, -75.3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_transformed = (
  # Whole bunch of transformations including merge and spatial joins
  # which transform the original lon and lat columns
  .pipe(turn_to_geo, 'lon', 'lat')
)
# This works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `gpd.GeoDataFrame` constructor properly within an inline `lambda` function:

```
df_transformed = (
    # Whole bunch of transformations including merge and spatial joins
    # which transform the original lon and lat columns
    df.pipe(lambda x: gpd.GeoDataFrame(x,
            geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x['lon'], x['lat']),
            crs='EPSG:4326'))
)

print(df_transformed)
```

---

```
  calories  duration   lon   lat                   geometry
0       420        50  6.23 -75.1  POINT (6.23000 -75.10000)
1       380        40  6.24 -75.2  POINT (6.24000 -75.20000)
2       390        45  6.25 -75.3  POINT (6.25000 -75.30000)
```